# Can you interact with a site that is only supported by IE from an android app?

Tags: java, android, http, internet-explorer, httprequest

I am trying to write an app that interacts with a website. However this website is only available to be used in the IE browser. Would I be able to still interact with it in the android application. Maybe using HttpRequest?

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Define "only available to be used in the IE browser"? What does that mean? How is this implemented?

Comment: Florian I meant when accessing the website on a browser it only allows you to use IE. If you try to use any other browser it says that you can't use it and that you need to go to IE

Comment: The question is: "How do the site authors do that?". Depending on the answer, the answer to your question is "Yes", "Perhaps" or "Not without too much work".

Comment: As far as I can tell they do it with a meta html tag. Authors of the website are being awkward at the moment about it. I'm guessing I could try and retrieve the html and try and interact with it like that? or is there a much easier way?

Comment: I doubt that a meta tag will stop firefox, for example, but I'm not a browser expert. Without information, experimentation seems to be the only thing you CAN do.

Comment: Ok looked a bit further into it and turns out it is javascript that is stopping it running on another browser. Disable javascript and it works. However because of the way it is coded without javascript doesn't work. But because it is just javascript a httprequest would work right?

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser, so technically you should be able to emulate everything in Java - but probably not a trivial task.